# When reading dataset with pandas it shows that the columns are shifted all one to the right and therefore the values do not align

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

When reading my dataset in pandas and displaying the dataset I can see that every column is shifted one to the right which makes all the values belonging to the wrong column.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
pd.read_csv("ACLED.csv", on_bad_lines='skip', delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
pd.head()
```

The image I included shows that normally the first column event_id_cnty should be one to the left like all other columns and be over ARG13046.[Image dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9MW7.png)

Comment: Try just using `pd.read_csv("ACLED.csv")`  Providing a sample snippet of a few lines of the CSV file would also help.

Comment: It does not work and gives the error: ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 4

Comment: Please provide the first 10 lines of the csv file in the original question or a link to the original csv file.

Comment: There is no link to the file. I downloaded the dataset on request without link

Comment: Then add a text block to the original question and provide the first 10 lines of the csv. It's extremely difficult to troubleshoot issues with CSV files without a reproducible csv file.

Comment: To be honest the alignment is so bad ... it might be okay and just *look* wrong. What's the result of `df.info()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `index_col=False` as a kwarg in `pd.read_csv(...)`.  This will ensure that the id column will not become the index, which is currently causing all column names to shift to the right.  [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is the full documentation.

```py
pd.read_csv("ACLED.csv", on_bad_lines='skip', delimiter=";",
            quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, index_col=False)
```